# Automatically record/log request URI as part of error in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling

Is there some way to get the request URI automatically added to `error_log()` output?  Errors currently look like:

```
[03-Dec-2012 13:56:22] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getStories()
on a non-object in /usr/share/php/MyProject/Model/Index.php on line 148
```

Is there a way to get the URL in there?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
    function debugErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
    {
       if(error_reporting()!==0) 
       {
          switch($errno) 
          {
            default:
               error_log("PHP Warning Debug: Server Request URI: " .
              print_r($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], true));
              break;
          }

          return false; // false -&gt; Execute PHP internal error handler
     }
    }
```